# Is it possible to run a function for each record in a set without using a cursor?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I've got two scalar-valued functions that take a user ID and role ID as parameters. The first, `GetCountries` returns a comma separated list of countries. The second, `GetBusinesses` returns a comma separated list of businesses. I pass the results of each of these to a table valued function called `StringSplit` that returns a single column table with a row for each value. I then cross join the countries and businesses to get all combinations.

The problem is I don't just have one role ID I have a set of role IDs. I could use a cursor and just repeat the process over and over again to get the complete list of countries and businesses but cursors are slow and I'm wondering if there's a more performant way.

This is how it would work if there were ONLY ONE role ID.

```
SELECT [Data] AS Countries INTO #TempCountries FROM StringSplit(GetCountries(@UserID, @RoleID), ',')
SELECT [Data] AS Businesses INTO #TempBus FROM StringSplit(GetBusinesses(@UserID, @RoleID), ',')

SELECT Countries, Businesses INTO #CountryBusCombo FROM #TempCountries CROSS JOIN #TempBus

DROP TABLE #TempCountries
DROP TABLE #TempBus
```

But in reality I have a list of role IDs from:

```
SELECT RoleID FROM UserRoles WHERE UserID = @UserID
```

So I'd have to run the above repeatedly until I have all the country and business combinations in #CountryBusCombo for each of the different role IDs.

Is there a way to do this without a cursor?

--EDIT
Yes, the code base is crap. I'm using what's already there in attempt to maintain consistency, but I can roll my own if the existing infrastructure is egregiously bad and it won't introduce regression errors.

Here's `GetCountries`

```
SELECT @CountryCodes = ISNULL((SELECT Country FROM HierarchyMap WHERE UserID = @UserID AND RoleID = @RoleID),'')
```

Here's `GetBusinesses`

```
SELECT @Businesses = ISNULL((SELECT Business FROM HierarchyMap WHERE UserID = @UserID AND RoleID = @RoleID ),'')
```

And `StringSplit`

```
ALTER FUNCTION StringSplit
    (
      @RowData NVARCHAR(MAX) ,
      @SplitOn NVARCHAR(5)
    )
RETURNS @ReturnValue TABLE ( Data NVARCHAR(MAX) )
AS 
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @Counter INT
        SET @Counter = 1 
        WHILE ( CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @RowData) > 0 ) 
            BEGIN  
                INSERT  INTO @ReturnValue
                        ( data
                        )
                        SELECT  Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@RowData, 1,
                                                             CHARINDEX(@SplitOn,
                                                              @RowData) - 1)))
                SET @RowData = SUBSTRING(@RowData,
                                         CHARINDEX(@SplitOn, @RowData) + 1,
                                         LEN(@RowData)) 
                SET @Counter = @Counter + 1  
            END 
        INSERT  INTO @ReturnValue
                ( data )
                SELECT  Data = LTRIM(RTRIM(@RowData))  
        RETURN  
    END
```

-- EDIT 2
So the starting point is the HierarchyMap table, where there are records that look like this:

```
UserID|RoleID|Countries|Businesses
Bob|role1|AU,GB|Bus1,Bus2,Bus3
Bob|role2|BE|Bus4
```

Expected result:

```
Country|Business
AU|Bus1
AU|Bus2
AU|Bus3
GB|Bus1
GB|Bus2
GB|Bus3
BE|Bus4
```

Comment: Yes you can increase the performance here considerably. Start by NOT using scalar function to return delimited lists. You should instead use an inline table valued function. That will be faster already and it will eliminate the need for a string splitter. My guess is you could probably write a single table valued function that would return everything you need in a single select statement. But without any actual details nobody can do much to help here.

Comment: Scalar and multi-line table-value functions are also slow performers well, so add that to the `CURSOR` and you have 3 of the worst performing options going, I'm afraid. Sample and and expected result well greatly help us here.

Comment: I would look into how GetCountries and GetBusinesses works, and create a new function

Comment: @Larnu I've added the extra detail you wanted.

Comment: @SeanLange updated with more info

Comment: A `WHILE` is just as bad an a `CURSOR`. If you do ever need to split a string, I strongly recommend looking at [`DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD`](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2) (or `DelimitedSplitN4k_LEAD for an `nvarchar`) for SQL Server 2012+ (or `STRING_SPLIT` if you're using 2016+ and ordinal position is meaningless).

Comment: Thanks for adding the DDL for the functions, by the way. Some Sample Data and Expected results should get us a real picture of what you need now; then we can turn that really slow performing query into something far far faster.

Comment: @Larnu added sample data and expected result

Comment: So the first data set is what your data looks like, before you create a delimited list? You need to fix your design then and not store delimited data.

Comment: Also, you're sample data has a column `UserID`, which isn't unique? That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Larnu That's the starting point yes. And I know the design is awful, but I can't change it, it was built this way years ago and too many components rely on it.

Comment: @Larnu that's because what is supposed to be unique is the combination of userID and roleID.

Comment: So what is the purpose of `GetCountries` if the values are already stored as a delimited list? Why not just `SELECT Countries FROM YourTable;`?

Comment: @Larnu From what I've been told its because data input is not sufficiently controlled in the app, so what can happen is there can be a delimited list that looks like `AU,CA,,BE`. I guess they're trying to filter out situations with a double comma.

Comment: Yikes this "design" is horrific. You have no way of knowing if your data is actually unique or not without some serious effort. This has recreated multiple one to many relationships in a flat file type of format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm going totally in the dark here, but it seems your table already has Countries and businesses stored in a delimited format; so I don't see the point in the functions `GetCountries` and `GetBusiness`, when you are already storing delimited data. I'm therefore guessing the table and column names, but you *should* simply be able to do this by the following:

```
SELECT C.Item AS Country,
       B.Item AS Business
FROM dbo.Users U --What ever table has your users in
     JOIN dbo.UsersInRoles UR ON U.UserID = UR.UserID --What ever table has your many to many relationship for roles
     JOIN dbo.Roles R ON UR.RoleID = R.RoleID --What ever table has all your roles
     JOIN dbo.HierarchyMap HM ON U.UserID = HM.UserID
                             AND R.RoleID = HM.RoleID
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(HM.Countries,',') C
     CROSS APPLY dbo.DelimitedSplit8K_LEAD(HM.Businesses,',') B;
```

[DelimitedSplit8k_LEAD](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/reaping-the-benefits-of-the-window-functions-in-t-sql-2)

The reason I don't use your splitter is because it's a multi-line table-value function, and uses `WHILE`. It'll perform terribly I'm afraid. The work Jeff, Eirikur, and other members of the SSC community did on the above function will out perform it any day of the week.

Ideally though, you need to fix that design, it's really bad. I'm happy to try and help you, but I really need some proper, consumable data to do that.

*Edit*: OP in the comments says that there are values like `'AU,CA,,BE'`, however, this was excluded from their sample data. If you do have rows like that, add a `WHERE`:

```
WHERE C.item <> ''
  AND B.item <> '';
```

[DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=020486dc167822801c604d510df39837)

Comment: I appreciate what you're saying about the design and I do push for good design on new components. But legacy stuff like this I can't get permission to change. I don't blame them, this particular table is referenced by hundreds of reports and two large ASP MVC web apps. No one wants to retest two entire apps and hundreds of reports just so a table has a better design. That said, I cringe every time I look at the code base or DB design, it's rotten to the core.

Comment: Yep, why I gave a solution that does work with your design, but still recommended you fix it, and offered to give you some pointers when you can @Legion .

Answer (score 1):

Do you just want `cross apply`?

```
SELECT c.value as country, b.value as business
FROM UserRoles ur cross apply
     StringSplit(GetCountries(@UserID, ur.RoleID), ',') c CROSS APPLY 
     StringSplit(GetBusinesses(@UserID, ur.RoleID), ',') b;
WHERE ur.UserID = @UserID
```

Comment: This isn't going to help the real underlying problem; the use of scalar and mult-line table-value functions, and Cursors.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I might be missing something, but the OP is asking how to create the table without using a cursor -- which this answer does.

Comment: I am with @Larnu on this one. Sure this answers the question the OP asked but the real issue is scalar functions returning delimited lists in the first place.

Comment: Sometimes you need to look beyond what the OP is specifically asking. Also we don't have the definition of `StringSplit`, which could well also have a Cursor in it (I wouldn't be surprised, based on the OP's current design).

Comment: Is there supposed to be a `JOIN` or `CROSS APPLY` or something between `FROM UserRoles ur` and `StringSplit`?

Comment: I get the error `Table-valued function 'StringSplit' cannot have a column alias.`

Comment: Think you just have to remove the `(country)` after the `c` and `(business)` after the `b`.